# Virtual Keyboad javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to Virtual Keyboard javascript any one have any idea

Comment: "Javascript for PHP" what do you mean ?

Comment: you mean a virtual on screen keyboard using javascript on top of php?

Comment: @user472949: I've removed the PHP tag/part of your question as it's completely unrelated to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

if you search from google with "jquery virtual keyboard"  keyword. you can find lots of code.
but you are searching for wrong type. its not php question. you cand do this with php. you need to search for javascript

may be [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/VirtualKey)

Comment: yep I need to implement this as offline mode